# Custom Dialog on CreateView method returns before firebase firestore onCompletelistener fetch the data to list

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

**Custom Dialog on `CreateView` method returns before Firebase Firestore `onCompletelistener` fetch the data to list. Thats why no view show**.

I made `RecyclerView` with `CardView`, on click on Card view i need custom dialog which fetch data form firestore..but before its fetch data form Firestore //statement return rootView is executed so no data is show in dialog

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreSettings;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;


public class DialogSetClassTeacher extends DialogFragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SetClassTeacherListAdapter adapter;
    private FirebaseFirestore databaseTeachers;
    private List<ClassTeacher> teacherLists;
    FirebaseApp smaTeacher;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Fabric.with(this.getActivity(), new Crashlytics());
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_set_class_teacher, container, false);

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setDatabaseUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.dbURL))
                .setApiKey(getResources().getString(R.string.api))
                .setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.appID))
                .setProjectId(getResources().getString(R.string.projectId))
                .setStorageBucket(getResources().getString(R.string.storageBucket)).build();

        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
                .build();

        boolean hasBeenInitialized = false;
        List<FirebaseApp> fireBaseApps = FirebaseApp.getApps(this.getActivity());
        for (FirebaseApp app : fireBaseApps) {
            if (app.getName().equals("SMA_Teachers")) {
                hasBeenInitialized = true;

            }
        }

        if (!hasBeenInitialized) {
            smaTeacher = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this.getActivity(), options, "SMA_Teachers");

        }

        databaseTeachers = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("SMA_Teachers"));
        databaseTeachers.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialogSetClassTeacherRecycleView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

        this.getDialog().setTitle("Select a Class Teacher");
        databaseTeachers.collection("Teachers").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    teacherLists = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {

                        ClassTeacher newDataList =
                                new ClassTeacher(doc.getString("name"), " ", doc.getString("email"));
                        teacherLists.add(newDataList);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        adapter = new SetClassTeacherListAdapter(getActivity(), teacherLists);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error : " + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        //before getting a data its return
        return rootView;
    }


}
`
```

Comment: The `DialogFragment` appears, but the data is not shown? You are certain that the `onComplete()`event is being triggered, data is available and still the `RecyclerView` doesn't update with that data?

Comment: yes blank dialog appers on click ..to check i made two toast ..one inside onComplete() and one before return statement ....toast just before return runs first.

Comment: pic1 [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c7Zhh3Pcyr4OYR-tpa95gBJeuHFYPuV8) pic2 [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qIv-JKdu25R_147DoSSwTWLoxZKR-thC)

Comment: problem is onComplete() is task which runs on background ..further line of code keep on executing ..and at end it return view before any data set to recyclerView adapter ..a blank view is sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please get the following lines of code:

```
adapter = new SetClassTeacherListAdapter(getActivity(), teacherLists);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Out of the for loop because you creating a new instance of `SetClassTeacherListAdapter` class and you are setting the adapter on every iteration.

Comment: problem is onComplete() is task which runs on background ..further line of code keep on executing ..and at end it return view before any data set to recyclerView adapter ..a blank view is sent

Comment: No, this is not the problem. You got those lines out but there must be something else. Please add your database structure.

Comment: [db structure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10DpQiQXLX8hlHzVa6_QaX9p2XaT9JapD)

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "inside"+doc.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    adapter = new SetClassTeacherListAdapter(getActivity(), teacherLists);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`  made two toast one before return and one inside for loop data is fetched check in pic
`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "before return", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return rootView;'

Comment: [screenshot inside for loop and fetch data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fylbuJDywDCduBuHwjEvi2AgKNurZik7) [screenshot before retun first its pops out then inside ones](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qIv-JKdu25R_147DoSSwTWLoxZKR-thC)

Comment: I will write you new code to get the name and the email, is that ok for you?

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?